# Can a subscription be owned by exactly one account or can it be owned b multiple accounts?

Tags: azure

I am planning to move my infrastructure to the Azure cloud. I need someone to explain the subscription model

Can a subscription be owned by exactly one account or can it be owned b multiple accounts?

Comment: Do you mean billing ownership or management access?

Comment: I meant Overall

Answer (score 1):

Azure subscription can only have one Account Administrator, but you can add multiple owners. All the owners can use your subscription.

Refer to this document for more details.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/add-change-subscription-administrator

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Comment: @mikhil  If the answer is helpful, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). If you have any further question, just let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft updated documentation, there is only one Subscription Administrator. However, there can be more than one Account Administrator.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/add-change-subscription-administrator

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30149898)

Comment: @Soham I don't understand. How is "According to Microsoft updated documentation, there is only one Subscription Administrator. However, there can be more than one Account Administrator." with a link for reference, not an answer?